# R-language: using UDF in SQL statements

Tags: r, sqldf

I am new to R, and I am trying to use my `UDF` in a SQL statement (via the `sqldf`
function). However, I am getting an error saying `no such function`

Does `sqldf` allow using `UDFs`?

Here is a code example:

```
mySum <- function(x,y) { ret <- x+y return(ret) } 
data1=data.frame("var1"=1:3, "var2" = 5:7) 
View(data1) 
sSQL1 = "SELECT var1,var2,mySum(var1,var2) AS sum FROM data1" 
data2 <- sqldf(sSQL1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE) View(data2)
```

On running I am getting an error message:

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such function: mySum
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code. It's really hard to debug something that we can't even see.

Comment: here is a code example:

mySum <- function(x,y) 
 {
  ret <- x+y
  return(ret)
 }


data1=data.frame("var1"=1:3, "var2" = 5:7)
View(data1)

sSQL1 = "SELECT var1,var2,mySum(var1,var2) AS sum FROM data1"
data2 <- sqldf(sSQL1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
View(data2)

*******
On running I am getting an error message: Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such function: mySum

Comment: Please edit your question to add relevant information. You can use the `edit` button under the tags

Comment: I did add the OP's sample code from the above comment into their question.

Answer (score 2):

### SQLite extensions

If you are using the RSQLite backend then RSQLite includes a number of funtions written in C that can be used from SQL and sqldf makes these available.  See `?initExtensions` in the RSQLite package.  If one of these already does what you want then that could be a solution.

### Adding SQL functions

Of the varous backends supported SQLite lets one add C functions, H2 lets one add Java functions and MySQL and PostgreSQL allow one to add functions written in SQL using CREATE FUNCTION.

### Text preprocessing of SQL statement

**backticks** In general, you can't mix R into your SQL statements; however, you can perform text preprocessing of the SQL by using `fn$sqldf(...)` and then using `$` for single value replacements or backquotes for replacing the result of an R expression.  For example,

```
library(sqldf)

mySum <- function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = "+")
fn$sqldf("select Time, demand, `mySum('Time', 'demand')` total from BOD", verbose = TRUE)
```

giving the following where I added an arrow at the end of the line that shows the statement actually passed to the backend.

```
sqldf: library(RSQLite)
sqldf: m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
sqldf: connection <- dbConnect(m, dbname = ":memory:")
sqldf: initExtension(connection)
sqldf: dbWriteTable(connection, 'BOD', BOD, row.names = FALSE)
sqldf: dbGetQuery(connection, 'select Time, demand, Time+demand total from BOD') <--
sqldf: dbDisconnect(connection)
  Time demand total
1    1    8.3   9.3
2    2   10.3  12.3
3    3   19.0  22.0
4    4   16.0  20.0
5    5   15.6  20.6
6    7   19.8  26.8
```

See `?fn` in the gsubfn package and note that the gsubfn package is automatically made available by sqldf so you don't need a `library` statement for it.

**dollar sign** The above was an example using backticks.  Here is an example of using $ to do the same thing. The output would be the same.

```
mySum <- function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = "+")
total <- mySum("Time", "demand")
fn$sqldf("select Time, demand, $total total from BOD")
```